# How can i get element by id in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, html

How can i get element id: `<input type="number" name="1" id="cant1" style="width:60px;" required/>` in node.js?
Actually i've got this: `var cant = req.param("cant1");` but i get the name's input and i need the id.

Thanks for help me.

Comment: Thanks for your help, however i need the id. The name i don't need.

Comment: node.js is server side.  The loaded HTML where an element with an id would be is client side (in the browser).  There's something fundamentally off about your question as it doesn't really make sense.  If you want the value of some item from the HTML page to be accessible in a request that node.js is processing, then the Javascript in the browser must specifically send that value with the request.  Or, if you are using a form, that value may be sent automatically with a form post.

Answer (score 1):

The ID is only used client side. The name is used to generate the form data that is sent to the server.

If you need the ID then you'll need to encode it in the form data somehow. Possible approaches include:

- Just using that value as the `name` instead of `1`
- Using JavaScript to copy the ID value on top of the name or the value when the form is submitted
- Generate a set of hidden inputs that map the name and id values (e.g. `<input name="the_id_for_1" value="cant1">`)
- Generate some complex data structure in JSON and post it with Ajax instead of using a regular form submission